# Data transfer element cannot have ALLOCATABLE components in gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am compiling a code in Fortran. If I use a recent version of Intel Fortran it compiles. However, I need to compile the same code with `gfortran` (I have `gcc version 6.3.0 (GCC)`).

At these two lines of the code

```
read(F%Unit) FileSettings%TCosmoTheoryParams

Write(F%Unit) CosmoSettings%TCosmoTheoryParams
```

I get the error `

```
Error: Data transfer element at (1) cannot have ALLOCATABLE components unless it is processed by a defined input/output procedure`
```

How to modify the code, keeping the compiler `gcc`?

The full compiler error, within the 'make' compilation

```
    mpif90 -cpp -O3 -ffast-math -ffree-line-length-none -fopenmp -fmax-errors=4 -march=native -DMPI -DEFTCOSMOMC -I../EFTCAMB/ReleaseEFTMPI  -JReleaseEFTMPI -IReleaseEFTMPI/ -c CosmoTheory.f90 -o ReleaseEFTMPI/CosmoTheory.o
CosmoTheory.f90:253:52:

         read(F%Unit) FileSettings%TCosmoTheoryParams
                                                    1
Error: Data transfer element at (1) cannot have ALLOCATABLE components unless it is processed by a defined input/output procedure
CosmoTheory.f90:183:54:

         Write(F%Unit) CosmoSettings%TCosmoTheoryParams
                                                      1
Error: Data transfer element at (1) cannot have ALLOCATABLE components unless it is processed by a defined input/output procedure
```

And the snippet of code where these lines are from:

```
subroutine TCosmoTheoryPredictions_ReadTheory(this, F, first)
    Class(TCosmoTheoryPredictions) this
    class(TFileStream) :: F
    logical, intent(in) :: first
    type(TCosmoTheorySettings), save :: FileSettings
    !JD 02/14 new variables for handling new pk arrays
    integer :: num_k, num_z
    real(mcp), allocatable :: temp(:,:)
    real(mcp), allocatable :: k(:), z(:)
    real(mcp), allocatable :: cl(:)
    real(mcp), allocatable :: valArray(:)
    integer i,j

    if (first) then
        read(F%Unit) FileSettings%TCosmoTheoryParams
        if (FileSettings%use_LSS) call F%ReadSizedArray(FileSettings%power_redshifts)
        if (FileSettings%use_CMB) call F%ReadSizedArray(FileSettings%cl_lmax)
        call F%ReadSizedArray(FileSettings%ArraySizes) !not used
    end if



subroutine TCosmoTheoryPredictions_WriteTheory(this, F, first)
    Class(TCosmoTheoryPredictions) this
    class(TFileStream) :: F
    logical, intent(in) :: first
    integer ArraySizes(1)
    real(mcp) :: valArray(6)
    integer i,j

    if (first .and. new_chains) then
        Write(F%Unit) CosmoSettings%TCosmoTheoryParams
        if (CosmoSettings%use_LSS) call F%WriteSizedArray(CosmoSettings%power_redshifts)
        if (CosmoSettings%use_CMB) call F%WriteSizedArray(CosmoSettings%cl_lmax)
        ArraySizes(1)=size(valArray)
        call F%WriteSizedArray(ArraySizes)
    end if
```

Definition of `TCosmoTheorySettings`:

```
Type, extends(TCosmoTheoryParams):: TCosmoTheorySettings
    !Just add the allocatable components
    integer, allocatable :: cl_lmax(:,:)
    integer, allocatable :: ArraySizes(:)
    !e.g. lmax_cl(1,1) is lmax for TT; zero if CL is not used; order is T, E, B, Phi
    real(mcp), dimension(:), allocatable :: power_redshifts
contains
procedure, private :: Initialize_PKSettings
procedure, private :: Initialize_CMBSettings
procedure :: InitForLikelihoods => TCosmoTheorySettings_InitForLikelihoods
procedure :: ReadParams => TCosmoTheorySettings_ReadParams
end type TCosmoTheorySettings
```

Type `TCosmoTheoryParams` contains only ordinary non-allocatable and non-pointer data components and no procedures

Comment: Please provide the exact error message that is including the lines above it (where probably there is a ^ sign as well to indicate whether error occurs). Also a MWE would be nice as well.

Comment: The error message gives you the indication you need: provide a _defined input/output procedure_.

Comment: @albert I edited my post to answer your question

Comment: @francescalus I am sorry I don't know Fortran very much, could you explain the meaning of that sentence? thanks

Comment: One example is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22692805/3157076).

Comment: these are just 2 small parts, no way to see how type(TCosmoTheorySettings) is defined.

Comment: I am sorry @albert, it's a huge code. In the Edit 2, the defition you asked (I hope)

Comment: I think we will need a real [mcve]. Please follow the tips about how to create one. It usually needs a lot of removing of unimportant code and yes, it is a lot of work.

Comment: what is `type, TCosmoTheoryParams` ?